# How to store some of the entity's values in another table using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

is there a simple way to persist some of the fields in another class and table using hibernate.

For example, I have a `Person` class with `name`, `surname`, `email`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `country` fields. I want my classes to be:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String email;
   private Address address;
   // ..
}

public class Address
{
   private Person person; // to whom this belongs
   private String address1;
   private String address2;
   private String city;
   private String country;
   // ..
}
```

and I want to store Address in another table. What is the best way to achieve this?

**Edit:** I am using annotations. It does not have to be the way I described, I am looking for best practices.

**Edit 2:** What will be the Id of Address?

PS. If there is a way to make Address immutable (to use as a value object) that is even better, or maybe not because I thought everything from wrong perspective :)

Comment: using xml, or using annotations?

Comment: Mapping relationships like this is one of Hibernate's base use cases, what are you having problem with exactly? Immutable address is going to be harder though, and will need more work out of the box. Also, is `country` supposed to be another `Address`?

Comment: @Jack - `country` should be a `String`, you are right. And i answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Hibernate 3.5 it is possible to define *foreign generators* (aka. JPA mapping), details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier).

It is pretty straight forward `Person` should implement `Serializable` then `@Id` annotation is added to `person`.

```
@Entity
@AccessType(value = "field")
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address
{
   @Id
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
   private Person person;
   // ...
}
```

There is an alternative but I really like the first one:

```
@Entity
@AccessType(value = "field")
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address
{
   @Id
   private int personId;

   @MapsId
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
   private Person person;
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. map `Address` as an entity and add a primary key (an auto-generated id)
2. map the relation between `Person` and `Address` as `one-to-one` (`@OneToOne` on each field)